# Fazer pesquisa num ficheiro .csv em C

Tags: c, csv

Olá! Eu sou nova em programação, e para um trabalho da faculdade, tenho que criar um projeto no qual tenho que utilizar ficheiros .csv. O programa em si compila, mas sei que tenho um erro numa função if, e não consigo identificá-lo. Pesquisei por exemplos, mas não encontrei nada. Eu e uma amiga também chegamos a fazer perguntas semelhantes no site em inglês, mas foram bastante rudes connosco, e não nos ajudaram. Vou deixar aqui o código, e o if com o erro está assinalado com um comentário à frente (é no último if, para ser mais exata). Basicamente, este código permite-me inserir o nome da cidade, dizendo se esta existe no ficheiro ou não, e depois apresentava as informações meteorológicas correspondentes a essa cidade, mas o programa para de correr depois de confirmar que a cidade existe. Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda. E desde já obrigada!

```
int search_date(){
char input[100];
char id_input[100];
char id_cidade[100];
char cidade[100];
char concelho[100];
char distrito[100];
int i=1;

printf("Introduza localidade a pesquisar: ");    
scanf("%s", input);    

FILE* stream = fopen("cidades.csv", "r");
if (stream != NULL) {

    char line[1024];
    while (fgets(line, 1024, stream))
    {
        char *tmp = strdup(line);
        if (i > 0) {
            strcpy(id_cidade, strtok(tmp, ","));  
            strcpy(cidade, strtok(NULL, ","));  
            strcpy(concelho, strtok(NULL, ","));  
            strcpy(distrito, strtok(NULL, ","));  

            if (strcasecmp(cidade, input) == 0 || strcasecmp(concelho, input) == 0 || strcasecmp(distrito, input) == 0) {
                printf("%s - %s - %s - %s \n", id_cidade, cidade, concelho, distrito);
                printf("id_cidade: %s \n", id_cidade);
                strcpy(id_input, id_cidade);  
            }
            else {
            }   
        }
        i++;      
        free(tmp);
    }
} else {
    printf("INVALIDO");
}  

FILE* meteoFile = fopen("meteorologia.csv", "r");
if (meteoFile != NULL) {

    char line[1024];
    char id_meteo[100];    
    char id_meteo_cidade[100];    
    char temp_minima[100];    
    char temp_maxima[100];    
    char humidade[100];    
    char pressao[100];    
    char data[100];    
    int i=1;

    while (fgets(line, 1024, meteoFile))
    {
        char *tmp2 = strdup(line);

        if (i > 0) {
            strcpy(id_meteo, strtok(tmp2, ","));  
            strcpy(id_meteo_cidade, strtok(NULL, ","));  
            strcpy(temp_maxima, strtok(NULL, ","));  
            strcpy(temp_minima, strtok(NULL, ","));  
            strcpy(humidade, strtok(NULL, ","));  
            strcpy(pressao, strtok(NULL, ","));  
            strcpy(data, strtok(NULL, ","));

            printf("A obter os dados...\n");

            if (strcasecmp(id_meteo_cidade, id_cidade) == 0) //o erro está neste if
            {
                printf("Informacao meterologica para:%s em %s \nTemperatura Maxima: %s ºC\nTemperatura Minima: %s ºC\nHumidade: %s \nPressao: %s hPa\n\n\n", cidade, data, temp_maxima, temp_minima, humidade, pressao);
                // printf("encontrei \n");      
            }
            else
            {
                // printf("nao encontrei \n");      
            }   
        }
        i++;      
        free(tmp2);
    }
} else {
    printf("INVALIDO");
}
}
```

Comment: a função `strcasecmp` compara duas duas strings, e no caso os parâmetros parecem estar corretos, pois ambas as variáveis são declaradas como `char`, mas essa função fica numa biblioteca, acho que **strings.h**, você usou um include no seu programa? algo como `#include <strings.h>`

Comment: Sim, usei as bibliotecas <stdio.h>, <stdlib.h> e <string.h>

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo desses arquivos csv ? pode ser um da cidades.csv e o seu correspondente na meteorologia.csv

Comment: O ficheiro cidade.csv tem 152 linhas e 4 colunas e este formato: id_cidade,cidade,concelho,distrito (Ex.: 98,Porto,Porto,Porto)                                                                 O ficheiro meteorologia.csv tem 152 linhas e 7 colunas e este formato: id_meteo_cidade,id_cidade,temp_max,temp_min,humidade,pressão,data (Ex.: 98,98,9.5,-0.3,76,1024,2018-02-12)

Comment: Aparentemente os valores do csv estão ok. Olhando o código vi 3 problemas: o primeiro é que teu primeiro i é inicializado com 0 e depois é verificado "if (i > 0)" então ele nunca vai ler a primeira linha. 

O segundo problema é que se mesmo que a cidade de entrada não seja encontrada é tentado encontrar dados metereológicos, talvez seja melhor colocar uma mensagem de "Cidade não encotrada" e sair do programa.  

O terceiro problema é o printf dentro do if que você diz que é o problema, ele está com os parâmetros errados tem seis "%s" e 7 variáveis, tem um "%" perdido.

Comment: Como sugestão eu colocaria um printf ante do if que você julga ser o problema, para poder ver qual o valor está sendo comparado, se não é um lixo em memória ou algum caracter a mais, por exemplo um espaço.

Comment: @Psico: Obrigada pela ajuda, vou alterar e ver se o programa funciona. Esse % perdido é de propósito, porque estou a referir-me à percentagem de humidade... É apenas para aparecer a unidade

Comment: @Psico: Já alterei o código conforme as dicas que me deu. Mas mesmo assim acontece o mesmo. Compilo o programa, introduzo a cidade, é apresentado o resultado de pesquisa do ficheiro cidades.csv, e depois o programa simplesmente deixa de correr... Então o erro não pode ser no if, mas em algo antes, já que nem o printf que me aconselhou a inserir aparece...